# RETURNING in INSERT INTO statement with a SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-insert

I am inserting data into a table and want to return the inserted data. The inserted data contains foreign keys. I would like to get the whole data with the joins of the foreign keys.

I have tried putting a SELECT in RETURNING without luck. Is this even possible or do I just have to do another query after inserting the data?

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (col1, col2, col3, foreign_id) 
VALUES  ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 1);
```

So in this case, could I have a RETURNING that basically would give me:

```
SELECT someTable.*, foreignTable.* 
FROM someTable 
   JOIN foreignTable ON someTable.foreign_id = foreignTable.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=06b55314eca15d1b9bdc0618b0653e58)

You can use a CTE for this:

```
WITH inserting AS (
    INSERT INTO...
    RETURNING <new data>
)
SELECT i.*, ft.*
FROM inserting i JOIN foreign_table ft ...
```

In this case the `INSERT` statement will be executed. The `SELECT` statement will be executed after that. This can reference the inserted data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) for that:

```
with new_row as (
  INSERT INTO some_table (col1, col2, col3, foreign_id) 
  VALUES  ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 1)
  returning *
)
SELECT new_row.*, ft.* 
FROM new_row
   JOIN foreign_table ft ON new_row.foreign_id = ft.id;
```

Comment: You are referencing the result of the CTE in your select statement. But this returns nothing. You need the RETURNING clause

Comment: @S-Man and a_horse_with_no_name, thank you both for your answers, i wish i could accept both, but S-Man was slightly faster so I accepted his. Thank you both though, it works!